# Docker - "image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform" while trying to build image

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, docker

I am following this link to create docker image using spring boot project
https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-on-docker

Already switched to Windows Container

OS: Window 10 pro

Docker Version: 2.1.0.1

Engine: 19.03.1

While I am trying to build image i am getting this error:

```
  A:\Projects\Docker\dockerDemo>docker build -f DockerFile -t dockerdemo .
  Sending build context to Docker daemon  99.84kB
  Step 1/4 : FROM java:8
  8: Pulling from library/java
  image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform
```

DockerFile

```
  FROM java:8
  EXPOSE 8080
  ADD /target/dockerdemo.jar dockerdemo.jar
  ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "dockerdemo.jar"]
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of "java" you need "openjdk"

https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk

This will be your Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:[some_tag]
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/dockerdemo.jar dockerdemo.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "dockerdemo.jar"]
```

This is what i found with a java query:

https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=java&type=image